# React Maximum update depth exceeded in functional component. How am i suppose to make "isWall" property true on mouse-down

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment, mousedown

Really popular project by Clement Mihailescu - https://github.com/clementmihailescu/Pathfinding-Visualizer-Tutorial/blob/master/src/PathfindingVisualizer/PathfindingVisualizer.jsx

He has done this using class component, and I want to use functional components

What I want to happen is when mouseDown occurs I want "isWall" property to be set to true.
I reckon I need to modify the useEffect but I don't know how to go about that.

```
function PathFindingVisualizer() {

const [Grid, setGrid] = useState([]);
const [MouseIsPressed, setMouseIsPressed] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    initializeGrid();
}, []);

const initializeGrid = () => {
    const grid = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        const currentRow = [];
        for(let j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            currentRow.push(createNode(i, j));
        }
        grid.push(currentRow);
    };
    setGrid(grid);
};

const createNode = (i, j) => {
    return {
        i,
        j,
        isStart: i === START_NODE_ROW && j === START_NODE_COL,
        isEnd: i === END_NODE_ROW && j === END_NODE_COL,
        distance: Infinity,
        isVisited: false,
        isWall: false,
        previousNode: null,
    };
};

const gridWithWallToggle = (grid, i, j) => {
    const newGrid = [...grid];
    const node = grid[i][j];
    const newNode = {
        ...node,
        isWall : !node.isWall
    };
    console.log(newNode);
    newGrid[i][j] = newNode;
    return newGrid
}

const handleMouseDown = (i, j) => {
    const newGrid = gridWithWallToggle(Grid, i, j);
    setGrid(newGrid);
    setMouseIsPressed(true);
}

const gridWithNodes = (
    <div className="grid">
          {Grid.map((row, rowIdx) => {
            return (
              <div key={rowIdx} className="row">
                {row.map((node, nodeIdx) => {
                    const {i, j, isEnd, isStart, isWall} = node;
                    return (
                        <Node
                        key={nodeIdx}
                        i={i}
                        j={j}
                        isEnd={isEnd}
                        isStart={isStart}
                        isWall={isWall}
                        mouseIsPressed={MouseIsPressed}
                        onMouseDown={handleMouseDown(i, j)}
                        ></Node>
                    );
                })}
              </div>
            );
        })}
    </div>
)

return (
    <>
        <button onClick = {visualizeDijkstra}>Visualize</button>
        <div className="board">
            {gridWithNodes}
        </div>
    </>
)
}
```

export default PathFindingVisualizer

Comment: This calls the function immediately when renderd `onMouseDown={handleMouseDown(i, j)`, you want to call a function onMouseDown, so pass it a function `onMouseDown={() => handleMouseDown(i, j)`

Comment: Alternatively you can make `handleMouseDown` a curried function to return a handler function, i.e. `const handleMouseDown = (i, j) => () => {...`.